# How we lost karma?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know, how we lost karma?
I was searched but nothing available.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121341/how-we-lost-karma?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can track the evolution of your karma [in your profile](http://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/?sort=reputation). Put your mouse on a question title and you will get some information on your loss of karma.

More information is available in the [ROS Answers FAQ](http://answers.ros.org/faq/):

```
    How does karma system work?
    
    When a question or answer is upvoted, the user who posted them will gain some points, which are called "karma points". These points serve as a rough measure of the community trust to him/her. Various moderation tasks are gradually assigned to the users based on those points.
    
    For example, if you ask an interesting question or give a helpful answer, your input will be upvoted. On the other hand if the answer is misleading - it will be downvoted. Each vote in favor will generate 10 points, each vote against will subtract 10 points. There is a limit of 200 points that can be accumulated for a question or answer per day. The table below explains reputation point requirements for each type of moderation task.
        
    1    upvote
    3    post a link
    1    add comments
    50   downvote
    25   accept own answer to own questions
    25   open and close own questions
    100  retag other's questions
    75   edit community wiki questions
    1000 edit any answer
    200  delete any comment
```

If your questions/answers are not relevant enough, some people will probably downvote. Try to read [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and other ROS questions before asking one, so that people do not end up feeling that you did not search anywhere before asking your question. Same goes for answers.

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-23**:
Thanks for you answer but I do nothing but i lost -10 and -2 point karma in 1 day, DO you know why?

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-23**:
As I said, other people can influence your karma, so it does not just depend on what you did... Well, it does, but also indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Accepting an answer gives you 2 points. If you then un-accept it again, you'll get -2 points, and if you re-accept it, you'll get the 2 points back. Looking at your profile, that seems to be what has happened.

The same goes for upvotes/downvotes from other people: Somebody upvoted you (+10), clicked again, probably by mistake (-10) and then upvoted you again (+10) on this question. Your other question about TFs has been downvoted once, therefore -10.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-27**:
I think we can improve the FAQ with this extra information. We just need someone with the rights to edit it.